# DbContext prematurely disposing when passed into another `using` block

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have one function that requires an active `dbContext` that is used in multiple places.  In some places the `DbContext` already exists so I pass it in and use it if it does:

```
public void DoStuff(){
     using (var db = new dbContext()){
         DoThings(db);
         db.SaveChanges(); // breaks, context was disposed
     }
  }

public void DoThings(DbContext optionalContext = null){
     using (var db = optionalContext ?? new dbContext()){
         DoInternalThings(db);
     }
  }
```

Is there any way to make this pattern work, or should I just make the `optionalContext` required and spin up the contexts from the calling functions?  Because then I end up with a bunch of this:

```
public void DoStuff(){
     using (var db = new dbContext()){
         DoThings(db);
         db.SaveChanges(); // breaks
     }
 }

 public void DoThings(){ // version without dbContext passed in - solely a wrapper - yuck!
     using (var db = new dbContext()){
         DoThings(db);
     }
 }

  public void DoThings(DbContext db){
       DoInternalThings(db);
  }
```

Comment: Is DoStuff and DoThings in two different classes or in the same class? The above code is working as it is supposed to work though, error should come when you dispose it from child method.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into unit of work to see if this is a better method.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not dispose an object that is passed into a function, because you do not own it and don't control its lifetime. Yes, spin up a context in a calling function and makes the context required, and it's up to you how to design that in a beautiful and convenient to use way.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create another context for the inner function.Use already created one if that one is already exist else create a new one as shown below.

```
 public void DoStuff(){
         using (var db = new dbContext()){
             DoThings(db);
             db.SaveChanges();
         }
      }

    public void DoThings(DbContext db){
        if (db =null){
           using (var db = new dbContext()){
              DoInternalThings(db);
             }
           }else{
              DoInternalThings(db);
           }       
      }
```

Good explanation about the behavior of `DbContext` and the `Using` statement from the Program Manager of the Entity Framework team.

**Rowan Miller (MSFT)**

> The default behavior of DbContext is that the underlying connection is
>   automatically opened any time is needed and closed when it is no
>   longer needed. E.g. when you execute a query and iterate over query
>   results using “foreach”, the call to IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
>   will cause the connection to be opened, and when later there are no
>   more results available, “foreach” will take care of calling Dispose on
>   the enumerator, which will close the connection. In a similar way, a
>   call to DbContext.SaveChanges() will open the connection before
>   sending changes to the database and will close it before returning.
>
> Given this default behavior, in many real-world cases it is harmless
>   to leave the context without disposing it and just rely on garbage
>   collection.
>
> That said, there are two main reason our sample code tends to always
>   use “using” or dispose the context in some other way:
>
> 1. The default automatic open/close behavior is relatively easy to override: you can assume control of when the connection is opened and
>      closed by manually opening the connection. Once you start doing this
>      in some part of your code, then forgetting to dipose the context
>      becomes harmful, because you might be leaking open connections.
> 2. DbContext implements IDiposable following the recommended pattern, which includes exposing a virtual protected Dispose method that
>      derived types can override if for example the need to aggregate other
>      unmanaged resources into the lifetime of the context.

Here is the original article of it : [**Do I always have to call Dispose() on my DbContext objects**](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html)

Comment: I think you've missed the point.  What if I then need to call `DoThings` without a `DbContext` instance available?

Comment: Aha..Modified. Please see that.

Comment: The easiest quick fix, but there is something wrong with the design and the code is not testable - ideally there should be a db context factory

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer dbcontext, but why? Why not something like

```
public enum thingsToDo  {myStuff, yourStuff, otherStuff };
    public void doThings(thingsToDo whatToDo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            switch (whatToDo)
            {
                case thingsToDo.myStuff:
                    //this is what's indside the USING statement in doStuff
                    break;
                case thingsToDo.yourStuff:
                    //this is what's inside the USING statement in yourStuff
                    break;
                case thingsToDo.otherStuff:
                    //this is in method 3
                    break;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Then one or all of the following:

```
doThings(thingsToDo.myStuff); doThings(thingsToDo.otherStuff);doThings(thingsToDo.yourStuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my thinking your code is doing what is asked to do. If you use "Using" block then it will call dispose method when it get over. I also suggest that there is something wrong with your design of code. If Dbcontext is being created somewhere else then its lifetime also controlled by some other function that creating it.

Here problem is that second using does not know that there is already one using block over there. This is how compiler is designed. Also I am agree with @Sampath code as well.