# ASP.NET MVC ObjectDisposedException when trying to pass id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What I am trying to do is create a function that will pass through the id of the user and then will load up a page that displays all the applications that a user has made to each driving instructor.

I have already made a function that will display all applications from the database regardless of who created the application. I have also made a function that allows users to create applications. I have also created a field in the application table named User_UserId so when an application is created and commited to a database, it will add the specific userId that created the application.

My question is, how would I make it so that when you clicked on show all applications on a specific users account, it would only pull up applications that have that User_UserId attached. Could I add UserId to the class that stores the input form and set the UserId in there to the UserId that is creating the application?

My attempts so far all end up with this error in the User Controller on line - `IList<Application> applications = user.Applications.ToList();:`

```
An exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I have a function that allows me to view applications by Driving instructors and that works fine, it uses a similar method where it asks for the specific driving instructor in the create form. Then I have a function that lists the application by driving instructor.

Here is the code. Some main points to make are;

- Primary key UserId in user class is set as a string
- In the class that stores the input data, there is no UserId field as that is passed in the method.
- The field in Applications table that stores the user Id is named User_UserId

Please inform me if there is any more pieces of code you require.

**User Controller that opens the view for GetApplications:**

```
    public ActionResult GetApplications(string id)
    {
        User user = userService.GetUser(id);
        IList<Application> applications = user.Applications.ToList();
        return View(applications);
    }
```

**IDAO/DAO Files:**

```
IList<Application> GetApplications(string id, XContext context);

        public IList<Application> GetApplications(string id, XContext context)
    {
        User user = context.Users.Find(id);
        return user.Applications.ToList();
    }
```

**IService/Service Files:**

```
IList<Application> GetApplications(string id);

        public IList<Application> GetApplications(string id)
        {
            using (var context = new XContext())
            {

                IList<Application> Applications;
                Applications = userDAO.GetApplications(id, context);
                return Applications;
            }
        }
```

**HTML view for GetUser that leads to GetApplications, Model uses User class:**

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Show Applications", "GetApplications", "User") ||
```

**Context class:**

```
    public class XContext : DbContext
{
    public XContext() : base("XContext")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new XInitializer());
    }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }

}
```

**UserService GetUser function:**

```
public User GetUser(string id)
{
    using (var context = new XContext())
    {
        return userDAO.GetUser(id, context);
    }
}
```

**UserDAO GetUser function:**

```
        public User GetUser(string id, XContext context)
    {
        return context.Users.Find(id);
    }
```

**User Class:**

```
   using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
   public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Instructor> Instructors { get; set; }
    }
```

**Application Class:**

```
public class Application
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Manual { get; set; }
    public string InstructorName { get; set; }
}
```

I have set breakpoints on the controller function that breaks and here are the results:

```
        User user = userService.GetUser(id);

        id = "1"
        user = null

        IList<Application> applications = user.Applications.ToList();

        id = "1"
        applications = null
```

When I continue and get the error thrown, I am given

```
        id = "1"
        applications = null
        user.Application = null
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it a little clearer: are you asking why you are receiving the `ObjectDisposedException`? Or why you are getting no results? I'm not really sure what I should be answering here.

Comment: @Xerillio Hello! thank you for welcoming me, sorry for not being so clear. It's a bit of both, I think I understand why the error is being thrown. I'm guessing it's because the context class is being disposed of before this method is used so it cannot get a list of applications for the user because the connection to the database is closed. I'm mainly asking how I can fix the issue of the error being thrown as I cannot seem to find a solution myself. I have added the context class incase this is needed.

Comment: Could you userService.GetUser pls?

Comment: @Sergey Sure. I have added it in for you now. Thanks for having a look

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see anything. Pls show return userDAO.GetUser(id, context); Thanks.

Comment: @Sergey I have included this for you now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DbContext prematurely disposing when passed into another \`using\` block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177455/dbcontext-prematurely-disposing-when-passed-into-another-using-block)

Comment: @ZivWeissman I have had a look at it looks like that is the issue I am facing however I'm not understanding it fully conceptually so I'm having a hard time implementing it into my application. I tried to create a new method that has a new instance of db context but I am receiving a different error from that.

Answer (score 0):

Your Application class is incorrect. It doesn't have UserId

```
public class Application
{
    [Key]
    public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public string Manual { get; set; }
    public string InstructorName { get; set; }
}
```

And I think you have the same bug in your Instructor class

You have the bugs in your DAO.

Replace

```
    public User GetUser(string id, XContext context)
    {
        return context.Users.Find(id);
    }
```

with

```
    public User GetUser(string id, XContext context)
    {
        return context.Users.Include(i=> i.Applications).FirstOrDefault(i=>i.UserId==id);
    }
```

And replace

```
        public IList<Application> GetApplications(string id, XContext context)
    {
        User user = context.Users.Find(id);
        return user.Applications.ToList();
    }
```

with

```
    public IList<Application> GetApplications(string id, XContext context)
    {
        return context.Applications.Where(i=>i.UserId==id).ToList();
    }
```

User service code:

```
public List<Application>  GetApplications(string id)
{
    using (var context = new XContext())
    {
        return userDAO.GetApplications(id, context);
    }
}
```

Your controller code:

```
public ActionResult GetApplications(string id)
    {
        var applications = userService.GetApplications(id);
        return View(applications);
    }
```

Comment: Using this in the dao is not working for me, where you state "i=>i.Id=id", I have to change the i.id to i.UserId as that is how it is named in the user class. I am recieving 2 errors: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'" and also - "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

Comment: @DerekJo23 It was a typo. I fixed it . Replase " i.UserId=id " with i.UserId==id

Comment: thank you, it has got the page to load up but the id of the user is still not being passed through as it is loading all the applications into the list from all users. Is it not because the userid that it requires is in the Application class database table named User_UserId and not UserId from User class?. Or are you trying to match the UserId in user class with the User_UserId in the Application database?

Comment: Can you show  you dbcontext User class please?

Comment: I have added it in for you now Sergey.

Comment: I  updated the answer. Look at the bottom.  If it is still not working then  can you show your Applicaton class too , pls.

Comment: Apologies but it hasnt worked, nothing had changed with using your code in the controller against mine. I have uploaded the application class now.

Comment: Your application class is not correct.  I added UserId . I quess you need to add UserId to your instruction class too. Add UserId in  Application db table and fill UserId column

Comment: I thought having UserId in Application would have solved it, I'll let you know what happens, I have upvoted your answer but doesn't display! Thank you